# Derivation of First order derivation of Fourier transform

Tags: complex-numbers, fourier-analysis

Let $R$ be $(-\infty,+\infty)$. Starting with: $$x(t)=\int_{R}X(f)e^{2i\pi ft}df$$We have its Fourier transform:
$$F\{x(t)\}(f)=X(f)=\int_{R}x(t)e^{-2i\pi ft}dt$$

Its derivation is derived as follows:
$$F\big\{\frac {x(t)}{dt}\big\}(f)=\int_{R}\frac {dx(t)}{dt} e^{-2i\pi ft}dt=\int_{R}e^{-2i\pi ft}dx(t)$$ $$=x(t)e^{-2i\pi ft}|_{R}+2i\pi f\int_{R} x(t)e^{-2i\pi ft}dt=(2i\pi f)X(f)$$

My questions are:

- Why $x(t)e^{-2i\pi ft}|_{R}=0$?
- How to deal with limit of complex number? To be specific, I would like to understand why:
  $$\lim_{x\to\pm\infty} \frac {e^{x(a+bi)}}{a+bi}=0$$, for $a,b \in R$ and $a^2+b^2 \neq 0$
- (Update) What are mathematical assumptions required for all of these above things?

(I will be studying complex analysis next year but I would like to know some useful techniques/ knowlegde to study Fourier analysis.)

Comment: Actually differentiation under the integral sign is not justified without any assumptions on $f$. Standard proofs assume that $xf(x)\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ in order to justify the differentiation under the integral sign.

Comment: You are right. Actually this is part of the lecture note for engineering student, so it doesn't specify clearly any mathematical assumptions. I will update the question accordingly.

Comment: You are getting bad results since you are using a bound variable in the integration for a free variable outside of the integration. For example, in this statement: $$x(t)=\int_{R}X(f)e^{2i\pi ft}dt$$ $t$ appears on the left as a free variable, but there is no free $t$ on the right to match.

Comment: sorry, it's a typo, I've fixed it.

Comment: Okay, but now what does $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}X(f)$ mean when there is no $t$ in $X(f)$?

Comment: Ahhh, I see now. Actually the initial formula of the derivation is wrong. I've edited the formula and the post accordingly. Thanks! :)